# Why doesn't tinyperl die set ERRORLEVEL on windows

Tags: perl, batch-file

When I run tinyperl on windows ERRORLEVEL is not set when die is called but is set when exit is called.  Can someone enlighten me as to why die which terminates the program doesn't set the exit code on windows?  Is there some special die handler I need to setup?

Thanks

**PerlDie.pl**

```
die "died";
```

**PerlExit.pl**

```
exit(1);
```

**Caller.bat**

```
tinyperl PerlDie.pl
IF errorlevel 1 echo Die: Error set to one or above

tinyperl PerlExit.pl
IF errorlevel 1 echo Exit: Error set to one or above
```

**Result**

```
Exit: Error set to one or above
```

Comment: Might be an issue with TinyPerl. Running the same scripts in Strawberry Perl is giving me your expected result.

Comment: **ActivePerl**: `PerlDie.pl` errorlevel=255 `PerlExit.pl`errorlevel=1

Comment: tinyperl appears to be a build of perl v5.8 .  Are you using this voluntarily?  When this was released Windows 2000 was current.

Comment: huh, if it didn't say `died at line ...`, then your `die` didn't get executed.

Comment: must by a bug in the tinyperl version I'm using then.  Very unexpected and annoying it was...

Answer (score -1):

[die](http://p3rl.org/die) causes the exit status 255.

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a comment. @Endoro wrote this comment yesterday already!

Comment: @captcha It is: daxim showed this is documented behaviour, and that therefore the test `IF errorlevel 1` is misleading. Ergo, the test OP wrote does not imply that `die` does not set an exit code. The answer to *Why doesn't perl die set ERRORLEVEL on windows?* is: It does (just not to 1).

Comment: @amon 1) `if errorlevel 1` doesn't test for **equal** 1, it tests for **greater or equal**, the test is _not_ misleading 2) target of the question ist **tinyperl**, _not Perl_, and we know now that the behaviour is different. This is **not** an answer to the question in any way.

Comment: @captcha Thank you for clarifying and explaining my misunderstanding.